# How to filter XDocument based on children attributes and keeping parent structure?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, linq, linq-to-xml

An xml tree needs to be filtered based on attributes. Child elements have the same name as parent elements. If the criteria for showing an element is met, then this element and all the parent structure needs to be shown.

For example the xml looks like (deepness level is random):

```
<Root>
    <Foo attr="xyz 123"></Foo>
    <Foo attr="abc 111"></Foo>
    <Foo attr="abc 222">
        <Foo attr="abc 111"></Foo>
        <Foo attr="abc 222">
            <Foo attr="xyz 123"></Foo>
        </Foo>
    </Foo>
</Root>
```

Filtering criteria is, that the attribute "attr" contains text "xyz". After filtering the xml should look like:

```
<Root>
    <Foo attr="xyz 123"></Foo>
    <Foo attr="abc 222">
        <Foo attr="abc 222">
            <Foo attr="xyz 123"></Foo>
        </Foo>
    </Foo>
</Root>
```

`XDocument` is used to hold the tree structure (later `XDocument_instance.Elements()` is connected to WPF treeview).

The following Linq command does sorting only the first Element level (after Root):

```
var Elements = from el in xdoc.Root.Elements()
               where
                   el.Attribute("attr").Value.Contains("xyz")
               select el
```

How to create a Linq command (or foreach loop) which would apply the described filtering?

EDIT:
A preferred solution does not modify the original data but creates another for the view (i.e Linq query).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// first make a list of elements that are to be removed
var forRemoval = new List<XElement>();
foreach (var element in xmlDoc.Descendants())
{
    if (!element.DescendantsAndSelf().Any(e => e.Attribute("attr") != null && e.Attribute("attr").Value.Contains("xyz")))
    {
        forRemoval.Add(element);
    }
}

// then remove the elements
foreach (var xElement in forRemoval)
{
    xElement.Remove();
}
```

Comment: This is a very good workaround, but it modifies the original tree. I'm sorry I didn't specify it in the question. I'd have to make a deep copy before filtering (as another filter might be applied later). A preferred solution would be Linq query.

Answer (score 0):

You need [`Descendants()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.descendants%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which will get all child elements of document :

```
var Elements = from el in xdoc.Root.Descendants()
               where
                   el.Attribute("attr").Value.Contains("xyz")
               select el
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't preserve the tree structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following LINQ:

```
var Elements = from el in xdoc.Root.Elements()
               where (el.Attribute("attr") != null && el.Attribute("attr").Value.Contains("xyz")) ||
                   (el.Descendants().Any(x => x.Attribute("attr") != null && x.Attribute("attr").Value.Contains("xyz")))
               select el;
```

Comment: If you use `DescendantsAndSelf` you won't have to duplicate the criteria.

Comment: I was trying same, but `DescendantsAndSelf` returns a collection of `XNode` and for `XNode` I haven't found any method/Proerty for accessing attributes. So I did this.

Comment: A very nice attempt, but it does not answer the question. This query removes elements at the top level only. But i.e. <Foo attr="abc 111"></Foo> is preserved. See the example for which elements must be removed/preserved if the element does not meet filter criteria.